# Smooth clamping a tensor

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

1. Is there a simpler and more performant way to do this?
2. Can it be done for each channel individually instead of having a global max/min, in a single operation?

Essentially "soft clamping" values above/below threshold/-threshold to boundary/-boundary

```
import torch

input_tensor = torch.tensor([[
    [[-19, -7, -5, -4, -3, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 19],
     [-17, -7, -5, -4, -3, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
     [-12, -7, -5, -4, -3, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 13, 15, 17],
     [-11, -7, -5, -4, -3, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 12, 13, 14, 15, 19]]
]], dtype=torch.float16)

# Define the threshold and boundary
threshold = 3
boundary = 4

# Apply the smooth clamping operation to each channel individually
soft_clamped = torch.where(
    input_tensor > threshold,  # Above threshold
    ((input_tensor - threshold) / (input_tensor.max() - threshold)) * (boundary - threshold) + threshold,
    torch.where(
        input_tensor < -threshold,  # Below -threshold
        ((input_tensor + threshold) / (input_tensor.min() + threshold)) * (-boundary + threshold) - threshold,
        input_tensor
    )
)

print(soft_clamped)
```

```
tensor([[[[-4.0000, -3.2500, -3.1250, -3.0625, -3.0000, -1.0000,  0.0000,
            1.0000,  2.0000,  3.0000,  3.0625,  3.2500,  3.3125,  3.4375,
            3.5625,  3.6250,  3.6875,  3.7500,  4.0000],
          [-3.8750, -3.2500, -3.1250, -3.0625, -3.0000, -1.0000,  0.0000,
            1.0000,  2.0000,  3.0000,  3.0625,  3.1875,  3.2500,  3.3750,
            3.5625,  3.6250,  3.6875,  3.7500,  3.8125],
          [-3.5625, -3.2500, -3.1250, -3.0625, -3.0000, -1.0000,  0.0000,
            1.0000,  2.0000,  3.0000,  3.0625,  3.2500,  3.3125,  3.3750,
            3.5000,  3.6250,  3.6250,  3.7500,  3.8750],
          [-3.5000, -3.2500, -3.1250, -3.0625, -3.0000, -1.0000,  0.0000,
            1.0000,  2.0000,  3.0000,  3.0625,  3.2500,  3.3125,  3.3750,
            3.5625,  3.6250,  3.6875,  3.7500,  4.0000]]]],
       dtype=torch.float16)
```

Comment: It is always true that your input tensors have a structure of  "rows" sorted in ascending order or is it just an example and in general no structure can be assumed?

Comment: to clarify the question, are you trying to set all values outside `(-threshold, threshold)` to `(-boundary, boundary)` in a way that scales relative to the max/min of the last dimension of the tensor?

Comment: @YakovDan Thanks for asking this clarifying question. The input tensor will actually be of shape [1, 4, 128, 128] with varying structure as they represent images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Is there a simpler and more performant way to do this?`

I'm not sure there is. If I'm understanding your question correctly, the replacement values depend on the relative min/max values of the input as well as the size of the input (ie 5 values below range has a different interpolation compared to 3 values below range). This means a different replacement mask will need to be computed for each input.

`Can it be done for each channel individually instead of having a global max/min, in a single operation?`

Yes, you can do this by taking the max/min along a dimension and broadcasting.

```py
import torch

input_tensor = torch.tensor([[
    [[-19, -7, -5, -4, -3, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 19],
     [-17, -7, -5, -4, -3, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
     [-12, -7, -5, -4, -3, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 13, 15, 17],
     [-11, -7, -5, -4, -3, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 12, 13, 14, 15, 19]]
]], dtype=torch.float16)

threshold = 3
boundary = 4
channel_dim = 3

max_vals = input_tensor.max(channel_dim, keepdim=True)[0]
max_replace = ((input_tensor - threshold) / (max_vals - threshold)) * (boundary - threshold) + threshold
over_mask = (input_tensor > threshold)

min_vals = input_tensor.min(channel_dim, keepdim=True)[0]
min_replace = ((input_tensor + threshold) / (min_vals + threshold)) * (-boundary + threshold) - threshold
under_mask = (input_tensor < -threshold)

soft_clamped = torch.where(over_mask, max_replace, torch.where(under_mask, min_replace, input_tensor))

print(soft_clamped)
>tensor([[[[-4.0000, -3.2500, -3.1250, -3.0625, -3.0000, -1.0000,  0.0000,
            1.0000,  2.0000,  3.0000,  3.0625,  3.2500,  3.3125,  3.4375,
            3.5625,  3.6250,  3.6875,  3.7500,  4.0000],
          [-4.0000, -3.2852, -3.1426, -3.0723, -3.0000, -1.0000,  0.0000,
            1.0000,  2.0000,  3.0000,  3.0762,  3.2305,  3.3086,  3.4609,
            3.6914,  3.7695,  3.8457,  3.9219,  4.0000],
          [-4.0000, -3.4453, -3.2227, -3.1113, -3.0000, -1.0000,  0.0000,
            1.0000,  2.0000,  3.0000,  3.0723,  3.2852,  3.3574,  3.4277,
            3.5703,  3.7148,  3.7148,  3.8574,  4.0000],
          [-4.0000, -3.5000, -3.2500, -3.1250, -3.0000, -1.0000,  0.0000,
            1.0000,  2.0000,  3.0000,  3.0625,  3.2500,  3.3125,  3.3750,
            3.5625,  3.6250,  3.6875,  3.7500,  4.0000]]]],
```

You can also aggregate via

```py
replace_mask = ~(over_mask + under_mask)
soft_clamped = (replace_mask * input_tensor) + (max_replace * over_mask) + (min_replace * under_mask)
```

But i think the `where` syntax might be more efficient.